# gradle: Exclude some tests, but allow explicit execution

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, junit

I want to exclude some tests from a (pretty standard) Java gradle project (which works using an `exclude` in the test section), but allow explicit execution of the excluded tests via `-Dtest.single`. Currently, the exclude also prevents executing specific tests via `-Dtest.single`.

Comment: You can check of values for `-D` test single is on the white list. If so, don't exclude it.

Comment: I ended up doing this; if you put this as answer, I can accept it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if such mechanism exits - from looking at the docs I see it's not.

A possible workaround is to configure exclusion via `-Dtest.single` property. If given test is passed via this switch, just don't exclude it.